# Blank space on table that can't be removed (Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a blank space in the table that I can not remove. I have a very long character string but the table does not stretch. Using:

```
@Html.Label (item.Description, new {style = @" word-wrap : break-word; width: 10%; "})
```

Everything works well until there, where there's space there should be the string, but now it is empty!

Image on link to see whats happening: http://gyazo.com/a1ba58140e8f94e2e4f93db388586877

Comment: You need to post more of your html/css/javascript. It looks like you are setting the width of the description to 10% so that would be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, the table doesnt accept %, i changed my width for px and now works, thx you

Answer (score 0):

Try `white-space: pre-line;` in the style

```
@Html.Label (item.Description, new {style = @" word-wrap : break-word; width: 10%; white-space: pre-line;"})
```